# How do I make a button behave like a checkbox with angular material when using a reactive form?

Tags: angular-material, angular-forms

I have a button in a form group

```
<button mat-flat-button color="accent" matTooltip="Hide Section" formControlName="visible">
        <mat-icon>visibility</mat-icon>
        <!-- <mat-icon>visibility_off</mat-icon> -->
</button>
```

I know formControlName won't bind properly but is there an easy way to make the button toggle from the visibility icon to visibility_off icon just like a checkbox without coding a custom check box?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we can solve this solution in many ways:

1.Use formGroup => code in .ts file:

```
form = new FormGroup({
  visible: new FormControl(false),
});
```

in DOM:

```
<button mat-flat-button color="accent" formControlName="visible"
    [matTooltip]="(form.get('visible').value ? 'Show' : 'Hide') + ' Section'"
    (click)="form.get('visible').setValue(!form.get('visible').value)">
    <mat-icon>
        {{ form.get('visible').value ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}} 
    </mat-icon>
</button>
```

2.Use formControl:

```
visible = new FormControl(false);
form = new FormGroup({
  visible: this.visible,
});
```

and set this code in DOM:

```
<button mat-flat-button color="accent" [formControl]="visible"
    [matTooltip]="(visible.value ? 'Show' : 'Hide') + ' Section'"
    (click)="visible.setValue(!visible.value)">
    <mat-icon>
        {{ visible.value ? 'visibility_off' : 'visibility'}} 
    </mat-icon>
</button>
```

I recommend that call function for better coding:
(click)="onClickToggleButton()"
and implement this function in .ts file:

```
onClickToggleButton(): void {
  this.visible.setValue(!this.visible.value);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Users find it difficult to understand code only answers with no explanation. Please consider adding some description explaining how it solves the problem or add comments in the source code at appropriate places.

Comment: The code looks like it should work but is kind of a hack(nice idea, I hope I'll remember it next time I need it) it directly acces the form group in the template instead of relying on the formControlName binding.

Answer (score 0):

You have `mat-button-toggle` is like a checkbox;

```
<mat-button-toggle value="CheckBox">CheckBox</mat-button-toggle>
```

Comment: that might work, if I can make it work like a checkbox not like a radio, did not know "multiple" will make it work like a checkbox